# function with list inputs in python

Tags: python, function

I am trying to create a function ex:

```
RotateElement (doc, lmnt_id, axis, angle)
```

`lmnt_id`, `axis` and `angle` are inputs that will come in a form of a list. Ex:

```
axis = [line1, line2, line3]
angle = [20, 25, 30]
lmnt_id = [1, 2, 3]
doc is a constant value
```

How can i call this function so that it iterates through the inputs. i want it to use line1, 20 and 1 when it runs for the first time but then line2, 25 and 2 when it runs second time and so on. I tried this but it only runs once:

```
for i in lmnt_ids:
    lmnt_id = i
    for j in axises:
        axis = j
        result.append(ElementTransformUtils.RotateElement (doc, lmnt_id, axis, angle))
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want:

```
for axis_, angle_, lmnt_id_ in zip(axis, angle, lmnt_id):
    result.append(ElementTransformUtils.RotateElement(doc, lmnt_id_, 
                                                      axis_, angle_))
```

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) will match up the three lists and assign the `n`th value from each to the loop variables in turn